# using Regular exprestion to validate IP Address in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this code in PowerShell and it does not work! any help?

I just need it to make sure that the string is a working IP not 999.999.999.999 or a normal string

just an IP [0....255].[0....255].[0....255].[0....255]

```
if ($newIP -match "(\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b)") { $x = $True}
```

cheers

Comment: you can find a ton of matches for IP address by googling or directly here at stackoverflow. See [__here__](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) for the formal matching (called also _complex beast_ :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about:

```
[bool]($newIP -as [ipaddress])
```

Comment: This doesn't work all the time. If you put in "10.10" for example, it will say it's a valid IPAddress because the it will convert it to "10.0.0.10". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988644/converting-a-string-to-an-ip-address for more info

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more compact one:

`\b(([01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\b`

Comment: For those stumbling onto this thread now 11 years later: this solution is not correct as the expression will evaluate 0.0.0.0 as a valid IP address which it is not. The problem is the \d which allows zeros.

Answer (score 0):

or even shorter

`^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$`

Comment: I wanted to add that I have been using this IPRegex and have tested it against hundreds of IP addresses. It works like a charm.

Comment: What? That's basically saying it accepts any combination of 1 to 3 digits and has a period between them...

Answer (score 0):

This works fine and errors if not full IP

```
$Name = "1.1" ; [bool]($Name -as [ipaddress] -and ($Name.ToCharArray() | ?{$_ -eq "."}).count -eq 3)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Colin. However, if this is an answer to the question (I am not sure) then it requires a little rephrasing of the explanation for clarity and readability and maybe a little formatting of the shown code.

Comment: Please take the [tour] at your convenience.

Answer (score -2):

The following will not work ^(?:[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$
Take for example the part that needs to match the last octet from the IP Address
[0-9]{1,3} - This will not match only number in the interval 0 to 255
Your best approach will be to dived checking of a single octet to
250 to 255; 
240 to 249; 
100 to 199; 
10 to 99; and 
0 to 99.

Comment: There is no word in main question that ^(?:[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$ should work. Instead of writing what will not work please try to write what will with some proper examples.