# Converting a partial IP address string to an IP address object

Tags: powershell, ip

Why does the `System.Net.IpAddress` allow the following strings to be converted to valid IP addresses?

```
 $b = [ipaddress]"10.10.10"
 $b.IPAddressToString
 #10.10.0.10

 $c = [ipaddress]"10.10"
 $c.IPAddressToString
 #10.0.0.10

 $d = [ipaddress]"10"
 $d.IPAddressToString
 #0.0.0.10
```

I can see that the pattern is that the last octet in the string is the last octet in the `IPAddress` object, and whatever the first octets are in the string, are used as the left most octets in the `IPAddress`, and zeros are used to fill the middle unspecified octets, if any.

But why does it do this? As a user I'd expect it to fail during conversion unless all octets are specified.
Because it allows these conversions, unexpected results like this are possible when checking if a string is a valid IP address:

```
[bool]("10" -as [ipaddress]) #Outputs True
```

Comment: http://ilspy.net/ can help you answer a LOT of those WHY questions.  https://www.google.com/search?q=ipaddress+tryparse has some interesting reading at the first hit too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The number of parts (each part is separated by a period) in ipString determines how the IP address is constructed. A one part address is stored directly in the network address. **A two part address, convenient for specifying a class A address, puts the leading part in the first byte and the trailing part in the right-most three bytes of the network address**. A three part address, convenient for specifying a class B address, puts the first part in the first byte, the second part in the second byte, and the final part in the right-most two bytes of the network address.